# Cannot boot into Ubuntu after dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, windows-8, ssd

My main OS is Windows 8. I have replaced my optical drive with the second SSD drive and installed Ubuntu 18.04 there. However, after finishing the installation process and restarting my laptop, I cannot boot into Ubuntu anymore. I have set the second SSD drive at the first place in the boot order in BIOS, but it seems like it's skipping it and automatically booting into Windows.

I've disabled both secure boot and fast boot options. 
Do you have any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: The best way will to be to repair grub: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've used this tool and I can finally see the GNU GRUB screen. However, when I try to boot into Ubuntu, I keep getting a message "Failure reading sector 0x140880 from 'hd1'. You need to load the Kernel first"

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Some SSD need firmware update. And many UEFI need UEFI update. Also some UEFI will not directly boot a drive in the DVD slot, even though they would boot a DVD. In those cases users have had to have boot files on internal drive. Either booting from ESP on internal drive or even creating a separate /boot partition on internal drive.